# Groovy Grape in high volume applications

Tags: performance, groovy, groovy-grape

I have seen examples of Groovy Grape being used for scripts to perform FTPs and other basic scripting tasks.  Is anyone using Groovy Grape in applications that execute a high volume of transactions? We are executing a Groovy Scripts frequently (up to 50k per hour) in our application and would like to use Grape, but not sure what kind of performance impact there is. I see the one of the Grape property files (ivydata-2.0.properties) getting the timestamp at the top of the file updated on every Groovy Script execution, so it seems there is some overhead.

Has anyone seen performance issues with Grape in high volume applications, beyond the initial jar download?

Answer (score 0):

Performance issues with Grape besides the first download are not known on the developer side. But I dare to say, that Grape is typically not used in high volume applications, thus there is no base for saying "there are no problems".